# Remove SideIndicator field from compare object output in powershell

Tags: powershell

I just want to use the list of servers returned from the compare-object output and I get 2 columns. InputObject and SideIndicator. InputObject has the servers I want, and SideIndicator has the '<='. I've tried to just select InputObject from the variable using dot notation but not having any luck.

How do I return just the InputObject values with nothing else?

current output

```
$GetAllVMs = Get-VM
$AllVMNames = $GetAllVMs.Name
$TaggedVMs = $GetAllVMs | Get-NsxSecurityTagAssignment
$TaggedVMsNames = $TaggedVMs.VirtualMachine.Name

$testing = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $AllVMNames -DifferenceObject $TaggedVMsNames | Where-Object {$_.SideIndicator -eq "<="} | Select-Object $_.InputObject | Sort-Object InputObject | Format-Table



$testing


InputObject                                                              SideIndicator
-----------                                                              -------------
server1                                                                  <=
server2                                                                  <=
server3                                                                  <=
```

Comment: can you provide the code that creates / compares the variable `$testing`

Comment: `$testing | Select-Object InputObject`

Comment: @Theo I think you mean `$testing | Select-Object -ExpandProperty InputObject` or shorter `$testing |% InputObject`

Comment: @TheMadTechnician I think you're right. Misread that and thought the output was supposed to just omit the sideindicator property.

Comment: Just added the previous code that results in the $testing variable

Answer (score 1):

The **simplest way** to get the input objects themselves is to **use the `-PassThru` switch**:

```sh
PS> Compare-Object 'server1', 'server2', 'server3' @() -PassThru
server1
server2
server3
```

The **caveat** is that the input **objects are still *decorated* with a `SideIndicator` NoteProperty member** (as opposed to being *wrapped* in a `[pscustomobject]` instance with `InputObject` and `SideIndicator` prperties), using PowerShell's ETS (Extended Type System).

As shown above, this property doesn't necessarily surface, but there are contexts where it does, such when you serialize the objects via `ConvertTo-Json` for instance.

Unfortunately, **the only way to avoid this decoration is to *not* use `-PassThru` and to extract the `InputObject` property value from the output `[pscustomobject]` instances**, which is what you tried:

> I've tried to just select InputObject from the variable using dot notation but not having any luck.

**Accessing the `.InputObject` property** on all output objects **via [member-access enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44620191/45375)** *does* work:

```sh
# Test command that compares an array of strings to the empty array.
PS> (Compare-Object 'server1', 'server2', 'server3' @()).InputObject
server1
server2
server3
```

If you're planning to collect all objects in memory anyway, this will do and is the fastest option.

Only if *streaming* of the results via the pipeline is needed (for one-by-one processing without accumulating the results in memory) do you need to pipe to `ForEach-Object InputObject` or `Select-Object -ExpandProperty InputObject`.

Answer (score 0):

You should pipe the output through `Select-Object` e.g.

```
Get-MyServers | Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $refobj | Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'InputObject'
```

Where `Get-MyServers` is the name of the cmdlet that you're using to get your server names, and $refobj is the object you're comparing against.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7